# How would you turn one line of code into multiple lines?

Tags: python

I was attempting to complete a Python challenge where you create a function that takes a word and returns True if the word has two consecutive identical letters. After solving the challenge I was looking at other solutions and saw this:

```
def double_letters(word):
    return any(i*2 in word for i in word)
```

Out of curiosity and to better understand the code, I tried to expand this into more lines of code and so I wrote this:

```
def double_letters(word):
    for i in word:
        return any(i*2 in word)
```

But I get `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`.

Why does this not work? How should it be coded?

Comment: You should start with learning how `any()` works.

Comment: That's a really terrible `double_letters` implementation, by the way, since it takes quadratic time.

Answer (score 1):

The multiline code should be:

```
def double_letters(word):
    for i in word:
        if i*2 in word:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

According to the documentation of [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) it takes an `iterable` as argument, and your line:
`any(i*2 in word)` is essentially `any(bool)`, `bool` here represents either `True` or `False`. So you are getting an error.

Also have a look at [`for-else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) in Python. These kinds of scenario are the perfect for using `for-else`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break down that single line code into equivalent multiline, it should be like this :

```
def double_letters(word):
    for i in word:
        if i*2 in word:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: You forgot the `False` case.